# DAQ connection best practice

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-acquisition, nidaqmx

What are the best practices for configuring and communicating with a DAQ? Is it better to configure the DAQ once and then leave the line open and communicate when needed or is it better to open, configure and close the connection every time I need to communicate? I am concerned more with stability rather than speed. What, if any, are the benefits of working with one way or the other?

System Specifics: NI USB-6000 DAQ, Python 3 with PyDaqMx reading three analogue channels.